# Serial port communication in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have used this code in VS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string RxString,ComPort;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";

serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;  
serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None; 
serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One; 
serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;

serialPort1.DataReceived += new       SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
  }
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = ComPort;
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

        serialPort1.Open();
        if(serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Start.Enabled = false;
            Stop.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            Start.Enabled = true;
            Stop.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

        char[] buff = new char[1];

        buff[0] = e.KeyChar;

        serialPort1.Write(buff, 0 , 1);

        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,        System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComPort = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

  }
  }
```

but it's not working, I have tried using an avr for transmitting characters and successfully tested in hercules what its transmitting. But it is not showing up in my program. Please help.

I have updated the code and its working fine for receiving part but not transmitting correctly, i am not getting any error it is just not working as it should have worked.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Do you get an error? Is no data received? Does the program hang? Do little green men get up and dance on your screen? A little more detail, please.

Comment: My "hello world" for serial ports is to first make it work "loopback" with a paperclip between pins 2&3 TX/RX.

Comment: You are not setting the required SerialPort properties, just Baudrate isn't enough.  Not setting Handshake requires you to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true explicitly.

Comment: What does `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` return?

Answer (score 1):

You must set all the properties of your **serialPort1**.

Also, you should try to debug at multiple place to help us where it's going wrong : Does **IsOpen** return true? if no, this explain why you receive nothing.

See MSDN example if you want to try something is supposed to work : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

Be sure that the serial port is not alerady open by another program and you have selected the good **COM PORT**. Otherwise the code looks good. (You could also looks in the RxString value each time you are passing by. (maybe many empty space or "/r"))

Comment: Ok I have added this code

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  
    serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
    //Provide the name of port to which device is connected

    //default values of hardware[check with device specification document]
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;  
    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None; 
    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One; 
    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;


  
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
}

Comment: I dont think the delegate was absolutly necessary but i'm glad for you that it works

Answer (score -2):

```
[Serializable]
public class Customer
{
    [XmlElement("FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Age")] public int Age { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeLastName()
    {
        return Age > 18; // Enter here only if it is XmlSerialize.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see that this has anything to do with serial port communications.